# Using jQuery, how can I check when all images have loaded within a dynamic dom structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding dynamic content (including images) to the body. I want to be able to tell when the images within the new dynamic dom structure are all finished loading.

**HTML:**

```
<button>
  Add dynamic content
</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Append new .dynamic-container divs to the body
  $('button').click(function() {
    var newElement = $('<div class="dynamic-container"><div class="images-container"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home4.jpg" /><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home-inside-4.jpg" /><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home15.jpg" /><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home12.jpg" /><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home-inside-15.jpg" /></div></div>');

    $('body').append(newElement);

    // Perform an operation whenever all images are loaded within a newly created div.dynamic-container element
    newElement.on('load', 'img', function(){
      alert('all images have loaded');
    });
  });
});
```

Unfortunately this is not working. What am I missing?

I have created a JsFiddle to show what I'm doing: https://jsfiddle.net/cseckler/y3mpo37d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rely on the `load` event if you append the images to the document (or even create them with a `src`) prior to hooking `load`, so what you want to do is check for completed images; see comments:

```
// Perform an operation whenever all images are loaded within a newly created div.dynamic-container element
var imgs = newElement.find("img[src]"); // [src] = skip ones with no source
imgs.on("load", checkImages);
checkImages();

function checkImages() {
  var counter = 0;
  imgs.each(function() {
    if (this.complete) {
        ++counter;
    }
  });
  if (counter === imgs.length) {
    imgs.off("load", checkImages);
    // They're all loaded or failed; perform your operation
  }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Append new .dynamic-container divs to the body
  $('button').click(function() {
    var newElement = $('<div class="dynamic-container"><div class="images-container"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home4.jpg" /><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home-inside-4.jpg" /><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home15.jpg" /><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home12.jpg" /><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home-inside-15.jpg" /></div></div>');

    $('body').append(newElement);

    // Perform an operation whenever all images are loaded within a newly created div.dynamic-container element
    var imgs = newElement.find("img[src]"); // [src] = skip ones with no source
    imgs.on("load", checkImages);
    checkImages();

    function checkImages() {
      var counter = 0;
      imgs.each(function() {
        if (this.complete) {
            ++counter;
        }
      });
      if (counter === imgs.length) {
        imgs.off("load", checkImages);
        // They're all loaded or failed; perform your operation
        console.log("All done!");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
img {
 max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  Add dynamic content
</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That uses the [`complete` flag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-img-complete) on `img` elements:

> The IDL attribute complete must return true if any of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The `src` attribute is omitted.
> - The final task that is queued by the networking task source once the resource has been fetched has been queued.
> - The `img` element is completely available.
> - The `img` element is broken.
>
> Otherwise, the attribute must return false.

(Note: "attribute" in the above doesn't mean "attribute" in the HTML sense, just the IDL sense; `complete` is a *property*.)